# Cloud service publishing to Multiple URL's

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service that runs 3 production versions (different customers) of the same application that are connected to 3 separate azure databases. Currently I manually deploy each making changes to the Web.Release.config for changes to the database connection and use the azure publishing wizard and change some of the settings to point at the correct azure instance.

Can anyone point me in the direction to automate this process so that one click publishes all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the recommended approach for deploying to multiple azure environments(dev, test, production)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516692/what-is-the-recommended-approach-for-deploying-to-multiple-azure-environmentsde)

Answer (score 0):

Please see my recent answer to the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24519742/809357

However, this only allows you to have multiple different configurations for different clients - a configuration per client.

And currently there is no way to publish simultaneously to all of your clients. You'll still have to publish 3 times, but you would not need to adjust any connection strings manually.